# MAPI Error : The information store could not be opened. [MAPI 1.0 - [MAPI_E_LOGON_FAILED(80040111)]]

Tags: exchange-server, mapi

We are upgrading from Win 2003 to Win 2012 R2 Standard , 64 bit system.
There's a code which sends mail and uses MAPI, so as of now we want to use the same because of our deadline, will have to get rid of MAPI after that.

I am able to download and install CDO 1.21 for Win 2012. But now when I am conencting via MAPI, System is throwing error:

> The information store could not be opened. [MAPI 1.0 - [MAPI_E_LOGON_FAILED(80040111)]]

Code:

```
   Set objMAPI = New MAPI.Session
objMAPI.Logon ShowDialog:=False, NewSession:=False,   ProfileInfo:=gobjINI.gstrExchangeServer & vbLf & gobjINI.gstrProfile

'Add a new mesage to the OUtbo Messages Collection
Set objMSG = objMAPI.Outbox.Messages.Add
```

Error is thrown on third line:Set objMSG = objMAPI.Outbox.Messages.Add

Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: What version of Exchange are you hitting?

Comment: We are using Exchange 2010 sp3.

Comment: Keep noted that CDO is death and will no longer with with Exchange 2016. The correct way would be to use Exchange WebServices EWS as referenced [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dvespa/2015/06/18/mapi-cdo-will-not-be-supported-for-exchange-2016/).

Comment: Currently some of our codes uses CDOSYS.DLL. Should i transfer these also to EWS?